# How to set div to outer height of children?

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation and a don't want to use JS for this:

[image]

There is a header (blue) then a div which might contain content (if not it should collapse completly) and then the body (gray).

Now I want to div with the green border left and right to fill the whole gap between the header and the body. The gap is caused by `margin: 10px;` on the div with the red border.

The only "solution" I have found so far is to set `padding: 1px 0;` to the div with the green border (see commented line in fiddle). Is there any better solution to force the div or the border to cover the whole height occupied by the child and collapse completly if there is no child?

I have no control over the content inside the div, so not using margin is not a solution.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5NW4/1/

Comment: That commented line seems to do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: instead of using margin on the red div, you could using padding on the green div - [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/w5NW4/4/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are looking like this :- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w5NW4/2/)

Give the `overflow:hidden` to your banner class for achieving the desired result..

**CSS**

```
 .banner {
    border-left: 1px solid #008000;
    border-right: 1px solid #008000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: yup this is the trick and we can achieve the result through this trick... @Fender

Comment: had to wait 4 minutes before I was able to accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `overflow: auto;` property instead of using `padding`.
It will work.

Check it at Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5NW4/3/

```
.banner{
    border-left: 1px solid green;
    border-right: 1px solid green;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to give `padding: 10px;` to `.banner` and removing `margin: 10px;` from the banner child element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5NW4/5/)**

Also, try to avoid inline stylings.